# Запятая в сложноподчинённом предложении

Tags: запятые, однородные-члены

**Спросит, почему Альтаир пришел к нему и почему оставил на крыше, после чего Эцио месяц провалялся в постели.**

Уважаемые знатоки, прошу, подскажите, нужна ли запятая после слов "пришел к нему" или это правильный вариант?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Запятая не нужна. Союз и соединяет однородные придаточные.

Comment: как я и думала, спасибо